# bootstrap for the tag class is showing normal HTML without the plane CSS effects

Tags: angular

```
    <div class="page-area">
      <h2>Home</h2>
        <div class="box">
            <h1>User name is <span class="text-success">{{userName}}</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <app-comp2></app-comp2>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>



import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Comp2Component } from './comp2/comp2.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Comp2Component
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

bootstrap for the tag class is showing normal HTML without the plane CSS effects

I am new to angular was working on bootstrap for the tag. I was using predefined class not but working  but the output is showing has to plane no effects on it

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "egg": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/egg",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "egg:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "egg:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "egg:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "egg:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "egg:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "egg"
}
```

angular.json

Comment: How do you import bootstrap? Via `link` tag in `index.html` or `styles` section in `angular.json`?

Comment: I have added into angular.json

Comment: Are you sure that the `bootstrap css` is added in the output bundle ? Try adding the bootsrtap CSS manually in `html`. If this resolves the issue then there is something wrong in your build process.

Comment: have you installed bootstrap? Via `npm install bootstrap` ? I just tried on stackblitz, bootstrap styles are applied https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzu7kn